# Unknown issue when trying to make a dropdown in html and php

Tags: php, html

Making a new tool and require a dropdown menu but it doesn't seem to work the way I have coded it.

Not sure exactly what the problem is. Have researched online but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
if(!isset($_POST["ReasonList"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please select a reason</label></p>';
 }
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Reason for Request</label>
<select id="ReasonList" name="ReasonList" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ReasonList; ?>" />

  <option value = "">Select...</option>
  <option value = "1">Original Engineer has left the company</option>
  <option value = "2">Actively involved in field work on customer site</option>
  <option value = "3">No capacity due to customer mandated deadlines</option>
  <option value = "4">Exception request by manager</option>
</select>
</div>
```

If option is selected then able to submit the form. If option is not selected it will give the error in the if statement - Please select a reason

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: `<name="ReasonList" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ReasonList; ?>" />` what element is this? it shouldn't be a child of select

Comment: Your `<select...>` is syntactically incorrect `name` is an attribute of the `<select>` like `<select id="ReasonList" name="ReasonList" ...>`

Comment: Your `select` should be `<select id = "ReasonList" name="ReasonList" class="form-control">`

Comment: can you explain this `<name="ReasonList" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ReasonList; ?>" />`

Comment: And the `<select>` has no `value` attribute

Comment: @VikashPathak Please dont amend the errors out of the question when you edit the questions code !!
.

Comment: @DanishAli Have a care when Approving Edits. This one actually edited out the error from the question :) which would not have helped the OP very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the corrected `<select>` element, and how a bit of code indentation make the HTML easier to read and debug.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Reason for Request</label>
    <select id="ReasonList" name="ReasonList" class="form-control">
        <option value = "">Select...</option>
        <option value = "1">Original Engineer has left the company</option>
        <option value = "2">Actively involved in field work on customer site</option>
        <option value = "3">No capacity due to customer mandated deadlines</option>
        <option value = "4">Exception request by manager</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `<select>` element does not have a `value` property and you accidentally closed the `<select>` before the `name` attribute.